# Finding maximum value from a file

Tags: matlab, matrix, max

I want to find out first maximum value (x, ymax) from an array from a  file, which contains

```
x y
1 3 
2 4 
3 1 
4 5 
5 4 
6 8 
7 8
9 8
10 8
```

The answer will be: (6, 8)
How can I obtain it with Matlab commands? I have started Matlab just today.

Comment: 1) welcome to SO 2) what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Hint to the answer:

As you are looking for the maximum you can find it by using `max`

Try to use this on the second column (or the vector `y` if you have it), if you want to find the location of the maximum you will need to use it with multiple output arguments.

Try `help max` and look at the examples

Answer (score 0):

```
b=dlmread('filename','',1,0);
[~,i]=max(b(:,2));
disp(b(:,i))% shows 6,8
```

You need to first delete the first line from your file ("x y").

Comment: If you don't want to delete the first line, you can use `dlmread`, as in `b = dlmread('filename','',1,0);`